# generate certificate in corel draw with dirrent names

Tags: corel-draw

I have created certificate designs for my friends institute. but the problem is he require different names on each certificate. so i need to manually create copies of same design multiple time and same boring copy paste work. 
I n design there is portion which need to replace each time.

is there any way to automate this process ?

Comment: Check the Print Merge option. File > Print merge.

Comment: @Rafael can i export them as a images design after merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Generate an excell table with a header.

**Name**

John

Jack

Etc.

**2)** Save it as txt or csv.

**3)** Menu > File > Print Merge

**4)** Import the table

You will have a window. Press insert field wherever you need the names and format it with font, color, size.

**5)** Then you have 3 options:

**a)** Merge into a new file. This will make a new corel document with multiple pages each with a name on it plus de design. Watch it if the design is complex and you have a lot of names.

**b)** You can use a virtual printer like pdf creator or Windows XPS Document writer and make a Pdf or XPS file with multiple pages.

**c)** Print it directly to the printer.